# Count occurences of different values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, count, compare

How to count the values in a column and after that, based on the results, to select only the lines with more occurrences ?

**Example:**

[image: reference]

We should expect to obtain the list of books with more "good" opinions than "bad": book1 (2 count of "good" and 1 count of "bad) and book3 (2 count of "good"); book2 cannot be selected because the number of "good" and "bad" it's equal; neither book4 cannot be selected - only one "bad".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation with an appropriate filtering expression in the `having` clause:

```
select book
from t
group by book
having sum(case when opinion = 'good' then 1 when opinion = 'bad' then -1 end) > 0;
```